# AWS lambda change instance type with boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

when i try this code to change EC2 instance type, it gives me this error

----------------------------------error Response---------------------------------------------------------------

"errorMessage": "Syntax error in module 'lambda_function': expected an indented block
"Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError",

--------------------------Lambda code--------------------------

```
  import boto3
def lambda_handler(event, context):
client = boto3.client('ec2')

# Insert your Instance ID here
my_instance = 'i-0cd1cecsdcdodid'

# Stop the instance
client.stop_instances(InstanceIds=[my_instance])
waiter=client.get_waiter('instance_stopped')
waiter.wait(InstanceIds=[my_instance])

# Change the instance type
client.modify_instance_attribute(InstanceId=my_instance, Attribute='instanceType', Value='t2.medium')

# Start the instance
client.start_instances(InstanceIds=[my_instance])
```

Comment: Can you post the entire script?

Comment: dear @jellycsc i updated the script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have some indentation error in your code. Here is a reformatted version:

```py
import boto3


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.client('ec2')

    # Insert your Instance ID here

    my_instance = 'i-0cd1cecsdcdodid'  # Stop the instance
    client.stop_instances(InstanceIds=[my_instance])
    waiter = client.get_waiter('instance_stopped')
    waiter.wait(InstanceIds=[my_instance])  # Change the instance type
    client.modify_instance_attribute(InstanceId=my_instance,
            Attribute='instanceType', Value='t2.medium')  # Start the instance
    client.start_instances(InstanceIds=[my_instance])
```